# EPS Picture is not located correctly by dragging and drop the eps file into texshop

Tags: pdftex, plot, eps

I am using TexShop to write a document. For inserting my figures, I have converted them to eps files and then dragged and dropped into latex environment. I have set the size of figures to be the same as size of A4, however, the results is that the figure is inserted like this:

[image]

That is, there are some extra spaces at left and top of the page, and therefore some parts of left and bottom of figure are not shown.

In the log file, I have received these:

> [7] [8] [9] <../../Desktop/Fig3_resized.eps> Overfull \hbox
>   (209.82327pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 113--114 [][]  [10]
>   Overfull \vbox (241.83586pt too high) has occurred while \output is
>   active

I just have dragged and dropped the eps file and I have made the eps file with illustrator and set the size to be similar as A4.

I wonder why this error and behavior happenes and how should I solve it.

Edit:

When I drag and drop my eps file, the resulting code appears automatically:

```
\documentclass[master,english]{kuisthesis}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[]{/Users/admin/Desktop/Fig3_resized.eps}

\end{document}
```

Here is the simple code that reproduces the same result. I have attached the screenshot of my eps file too.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! Can you please show us a short complilable tex code resuling in your issue. In your case can you also show us the two images?

Comment: Thankyou! My code is a bit long, However, I will post related parts. What do you mean by two images? The original one and the one that latex outputs?

Comment: Please provide an MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, which reproduce your problem. I suspect that you images have white space on top and left their side ...

Comment: Thankyou! I have provided a simple code. I am using a document class provided by our department. So I do not know what information about that can be useful

Comment: I assume you are using A4 paper. But LaTeX has marigns set so the actual print size is smaller than the full A4 paper. Would you please let us at least see the line where you include the graphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your class `kuisthesis` uses a4 paper format. Because you gave us no link to that class I simply changed in the following the class to `report`. Because your shows image is added as `*.png` file I used `pdflatex` to compile and used the filename `498944.png` for your image.

Okay, now please test the following code and see, that I added `width=\textwidth` to your `\includegraphics` command and used package `showframe` to visualize the typing area:

```
\documentclass[master,english]{report} %kuisthesis

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{showframe} % <======================================


\begin{document} 
%\includegraphics[]{498944.png}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{498944.png} % <==============

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: result]

As you can see you have a small space in your image at the beginning (red arrow, marked 1) and filled the complete `\textwidth` (red arrow, marked 2).

Note: You simply can not use the complete `\paperwidth`, because there are the margins on the right (red arrow with r) and left (red arrow with l) you have to respect.

[image: typing area]

Comment: Thankyou very much. It was very helpful. I also used usepackage{showframe} to understand about the white spaces and I have figured out it is due to how to save the illustrator. When using illustrator to save as eps files, I should save using artboards to avoid this problem. Thank you very much

Comment: @Kadaj13 You are welcome!